# android load class from jar file

Tags: java, android, jar

I have written a Java Classloader to load classes from a `.jar` file.

However when I load a Class I get a `ClassNotFoundException`.  The `.jar` file is located in folder assets. Before the operation I copied the `.jar` file in another directory.

Why does it happen and how can I load class from jar file?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try {
        final File dexInternalStoragePath = new File(getDir("lib", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), SECONDARY_DEX_NAME);
        (new PrepareDexTask()).execute(dexInternalStoragePath);
        if (dexInternalStoragePath.exists()) {
            final File optimizedDexOutputPath = getDir("outdex", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(),
                    optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(), null, getClassLoader());
            try {
                JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath());
                Enumeration<?> e = jarFile.entries();

                URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath() + "!/") };
                URLClassLoader cl1 = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

                while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                    JarEntry je = (JarEntry) e.nextElement();
                    if (je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String className = je.getName().substring(0, je.getName().length() - 6);
                    className = className.replace('/', '.');
                    if (className.equals("com.common.lvl.LibraryProvider")) {
                        LibraryInterface lib = (LibraryInterface) Class.forName(className, true,  cl1).newInstance();
                        //Class<?> libProviderClazz = cl1.loadClass(className);
                        //LibraryInterface lib = (LibraryInterface) libProviderClazz.newInstance();
                        lib.CheckLVL(this, "hello");
                    }
                }

                // Class<?> libProviderClazz =
                // cl.loadClass("com.common.lvl.LibraryProvider");
                // LibraryInterface lib = (LibraryInterface)
                // libProviderClazz.newInstance();
                // lib.CheckLVL(this, "hello");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.Instance().WriteLine(this, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}

private boolean prepareDex(File dexInternalStoragePath) {
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    OutputStream dexWriter = null;

    try {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(getAssets().open(SECONDARY_DEX_NAME));
        dexWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dexInternalStoragePath));
        byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
        int len;
        while ((len = bis.read(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
            dexWriter.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        dexWriter.close();
        bis.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (dexWriter != null) {
            try {
                dexWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (bis != null) {
            try {
                bis.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

private class PrepareDexTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(File... dexInternalStoragePaths) {
        prepareDex(dexInternalStoragePaths[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed grammar, clarified text into paragraphs, some formatting

Answer (score 0):

Add your jar file, like below

go to -> **project properties in eclipse -> java build path -> Libraries -> Add External Jar**, And browse and locate you jar file.

[image]

Comment: you can accept answer if it helped to you. and upvote

Comment: @Blackraven: It would be helpful to specify why this is unsuitable for your case. And to put this constraint in your question, if you haven't done that already. That would help later people with similar questions to know what answers would apply to them.